# Remove the .html from the end of a URL if there are two times occurred in magento 2

Tags: .htaccess

How do I remove the .html from the end of a URL if there are two times occurred in magento 2 using .htaccess

I write this code

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: May be something like routing is provided by magento so you don't have to write htaccess rule for that.

Comment: so what sholud i do for remove the .html from the end of a URL if there are two times occurred in magento 2

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something else at work. Removing suffixes can be done in the Magento configuration - not using rewrite rules. Login to your admin panel, goto **Stores->Configuration->Catalog**: click on the catalog search tab

Here you can remove the **Product URL Suffix** and **Category URL Suffix** by removing `.html` as shown below:

[image]